# JWTAuthentication not working in asp.net core 2.0 after migrate from 1.1 to 2.0 with System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt - 5.1.4 update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt

Error

Error   CS0619  'JwtBearerAppBuilderExtensions.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(IApplicationBuilder, JwtBearerOptions)' is obsolete: 'See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=845470'

Here is the code for the JWT authentication

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = key,
                    ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
                    ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,

                    // When receiving a token, check that it is still valid.
                    ValidateLifetime = true,

                    // This defines the maximum allowable clock skew - i.e. provides a tolerance on the token expiry time 
                    // when validating the lifetime. As we're creating the tokens locally and validating them on the same 
                    // machines which should have synchronised time, this can be set to zero. Where external tokens are
                    // used, some leeway here could be useful.
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)
                }
            });
```

The same code was working fine in asp.net core 1.1 I, have just migrate from core 1.1 to core 2.0 and updated the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt(5.1.1) to (5.1.4)

**ConfigureServices**

```
RSAParameters keyParams = RsaKeyUtils.GetRandomKey();
            key = new RsaSecurityKey(keyParams);
            tokenOptions = new TokenAuthOptions()
            {
                Audience = TokenAudience,
                Issuer = TokenIssuer,
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature)
            };
            services.AddSingleton<TokenAuthOptions>(tokenOptions);
            services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
            {
                auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            });
```

I tried the solution posted in this question [Authentication in dot net core preview-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753666/authentication-in-dot-net-core-preview-2-0) . But the solution is not working getting an error as  **IServiceCollection doesn't contain the definition for AddJwtBearerAuthentication**

Tried to implement https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/c5b566ed4abffac4cd7011e0465e012cf503c871/samples/JwtBearerSample/Startup.cs#L47-L53 
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1055
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/

500 internal server error.

The same code was working perfectly on asp.net core 1.1. When upgrade to 2.0 the issue occur.

Please anyone let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method for adding Jwt Bearer Authentication has changed in ASP.NET Core 2.0. See the [latest version](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/JwtBearerSample/Startup.cs#L47) of the sample you linked.

You need to register the Jwt Bearer Authentication process as a service, rather than a middleware component. See the relevant code in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddJwtBearer(...);
```

Try this in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
    {
        jwt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = key,
            ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
            ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,

            // When receiving a token, check that it is still valid.
            ValidateLifetime = true,

            // This defines the maximum allowable clock skew - i.e. provides a tolerance on the token expiry time
            // when validating the lifetime. As we're creating the tokens locally and validating them on the same
            // machines which should have synchronised time, this can be set to zero. Where external tokens are
            // used, some leeway here could be useful.
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)
        };
     });

services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
{
     auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
             .Build());
});
```

And make sure you have this in `Configure`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

As I can't test this against your scenario, there's every chance it won't work first time. Be sure to be specific when you include any further information that comes from this.

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154018/46129183.